# how to send/receive data securely in backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js, security, restful-authentication

I have created RESTFUL urls that respond with some JSON data when fetched by backbone.

So a url like `/lists` responds with a json array of user-created `lists`. My want that if the url is accessed by address bar input like `mydomain.com/lists`, the json data is displayed in text on browser. I want the server to respond only if the url is accessed from within the application. Can somebody provide me some hints on how to achieve this?

Comment: You cannot do that. Everything the app can do, the browser that hosts the app can also do.

Comment: And you are probably going to hate developer tools like Firebug. They give users a lot of insight into (and ways to mess with) your app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like @Thilo said, you're not going to be able to do prevent a person with the right tools to see what's coming across the wire, Firebug's console/net tabs already keep track of requests and show the contents of responses.

That being said, what you can do is check whether the HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH HTTP header is set to 'XMLHttpRequest', and only return the JSON in this case. Backbone makes an Ajax call so this will always be the case with the Backbone calls (in modern browsers). Again this won't help much except for people who type it into the address bar directly (and do a normal GET request) won't see the JSON.

Comment: is `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH` foolproof method to check for ajax requests or do I need to place more checks on the server side?

Comment: jQuery will always set this header during an Ajax request, check your Ajax library.

Comment: Re "foolproof". jQuery requests will have it, but anyone who is making the request can also add this header. Again, this only helps against people who type it into the address bar directly. If someone wanted to "hack" it, they could.